# Cannot use prepare statement on locally declared variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In a procedure I want to select a value from a specific table in all databases. I developed a code and reached to this point:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE dynamic_query LONGTEXT;

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000000;


SET dynamic_query = (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            "SELECT option_name AS _key, option_value as _value from ",
            TABLE_NAME, 
            " where option_name like '",
            "something%'" SEPARATOR ' union ') 
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                CONCAT(`database_name`,'.',`table_prefix`,'options') as TABLE_NAME 
            FROM `tablename`
            WHERE `database_name` <> '' AND `table_prefix` <> ''
        ) AS tmp

);
SELECT dynamic_query;

END
```

And I copy the output and execute it and it works fine. But when I add a prepare statement like below I get an error which is mentioned in [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13572).

```
PREPARE result_query FROM dynamic_query;
EXECUTE result_query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE result_query;
```

Is there any other way so I can get my desired output?

P.S.: I'm using `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000000;` to expand group_concat's limit but I prefer another way because the number of databases are growing.

Comment: Use a user defined variable instead (ie one prefixed @).

Comment: @P.Salmon when I use a user defined variable and assign it with `group_concat()` output, it is incomplete. and that's why I used `DECLARE dynamic_query LONGTEXT;`

Comment: You cannot use a declared variable in a prepared statement and a user defined variable is truncated. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294955/storage-limits-of-mysql-user-defined-variables discusses the limits on user defined variables.

Comment: @P.Salmon is there a way to expand user defined variable limit so it won't get truncated? Or in general a way to get my desired output..